# Entity Framework 6, Model First, Primary key inheritence

Tags: entity-framework-6

With Code first i've the following :

```
public class Key
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Key
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}

public class Department : Key
{
    public string DepName { get; set; }
}

Public class Context : DbContext
{
     Public Context() : base("name:DefaultConnection")
     {

     }
     Public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
     Public DbSet<Department> Departments{get; set;}
}
```

This code first generates for me two tables only in the database, Employee table with two primary keys (Id, CompanyId) inherited from class Key, and Department table with two primary keys (Id, CompanyId) inherited from class Key.
I lost hours trying to do the same behavior using model first approach but i couldn't.
I'll appreciate if any Entity framwork professional can help with that :)

Comment: Do you really mean *model first*. Or maybe *database first*?

Comment: In case of database first i'll get the database as i need but i will not get entities such mentioned above in the Question, so yes i really mean database first

Comment: I asked because model first ≠ database first. But I guess it's database first.